# Is it possible to have a java compiler in unity?

Tags: api, unity-game-engine

I have this homework where I should create an android application with a java compiler in it. the application i'm supposed to do is an educational application, with tutorials in it, my main problem is how to place a compiler in Unity. I've been searching the whole internet but can't seem to find what i need.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "place a compiler"?   do you want to to use a compiled unity program that can compile java code or do you want to compile a unity project with java?

I think thats not a thing you can get a fast answer on how to do it.

If you have a functioning java compiler in whatever language you can bind to C# you for sure can compile java code with a c# application.

Edit:
And ofcourse its possible to write kind of a "java syntax string to c# parser" in c# on a really basic level yourself, if that is what you want.

Comment: The reason why i mention Unity is that It's the only thing that comes to my mind when it comes to creating android app, but the real intention is to create an application in android using any platform that has a java compiler function in it. I'm trying to find tutorials but can't seem to find any.

Comment: dont use Unity!  try xamarin or similar java libraries.

Comment: https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/03/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and-9/    a compiler is just like a parser and thats what you need to do.